# Can we achieve Autodesk quantity take off feature in Autodesk Forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to Implement some features related to quantity take-off in Autodesk Forge viewer based on some criteria (draw a rectangle, based on properties, etc).

Do you have any extension for this feature in Forge viewer?

Comment: Not clear of the question.  But if the suggestion below with RCDB is not enough, could it be that you are asking 2D tool?  
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/edit2d-use/
(FYI - Takeoff read API is expected to come near future.)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this project [Forge RCDB](https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io)
It's a pretty big demo project with a lot of different extensions.

There's a demo of plant factory with graphs based on properties

[image: Forge RCDB Plant Factory]

Visual reports for AEC

[image: Visual Reports AEC]

Depending of what you want to achieve, you will find a lot of helpful exemples.

All the code is available on GitHub : [Forge RCDB Github](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs)

Comment: Thanks, I will look the above sample and let you know.